# function .data() not reading content onCreate FIrebase cloud trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I updated all my sdk and firebase nodejs, now i'm trying to notify all my admins about users requests.

well, when something is created the database trigger the function but it return empty to my  snap.data();

```
exports.sendAdminNotification = functions.firestore
    .document('Itapetininga SP/Shangrila/Relatorio/{id}').onCreate((snap, context) => {


const morador = snap.data();

function parse(str) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1),
        i = 0;

    return str.replace(/%s/g, () => args[i++]);
}
console.log('its working: ',morador.mensagem);

let msge = morador.mensagem; // 
s = parse('MORADOR %s, SOLICITA SERVICO', morador.nome);
let topic = "relatorio";
let payload = {
    notification: {
        title: s,
        body: morador.mensagem,
        sound: 'default',
        badge: '1'
    }
};

return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload);

  //
});
```

I want to read the content which was created

**SOLVED

Firestore bug: Can't deploy a trigger function if there is space in the collection name